# How to Resize (both height and width) KendoGrid in Angular?(Not the Column resizing)

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have a `Kendo grid` , which is to be resized like `Kendo-window` but there are some documents telling about column resizing by the below commands - **[resizable]** and **[minResizableWidth]**, For example:-

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" [resizable]="true" style="height: 300px">

<kendo-grid-column-group title="Product Info">
                <kendo-grid-column
                    field="ProductID"
                    [width]="50"
                    [minResizableWidth]="30"
                    title="ID">
                </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid-column-group>

</kendo-grid>
```

Is there any commands like `[minResizableWidth]` to  tag `<kendo-grid`>?

I tried with Kendo-panes and Kendo windows ( output by Kendo windows is given in this link https://angular-xuadgj.stackblitz.io/  and Stackblitz code is given in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuadgj?file=src%2Findex.html) , but not satisfied with outputs.

Expected Output: **Resizable KendoGrid** whose width and height must be controlled by dragging the mouse button.

Comment: You can try https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/advanced-features/responsive/

Comment: @Aditya Still same effect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for **Method 2 by Kendo grid** in Stackoverflow solution. The First solution by kendo window cannot restrict the height, since it show the **white spaces**. We can change the scrollable  property of the Kendo splitter pane by setting [scrollable]="false".